# qpdf encryption of a pdf file

Tags: encryption, pdf

Is there a way to encrypt a pdf with 128AES using only preinstalled ubuntu software of software from main repository? I noticed that exproting from libre office into pdf (one possibility) encrypts it whith a week encryption. Is there a way to to it e.g. using qpdf?

Comment: Using a qpdf it is possible to chose user and owner password. I am a totally new to ubuntu and I want just to set a password which prevents the pdf to be opened.

Answer (score 11):

After installing qpdf, you can encrypt pdf with password of your choice from command line in the following way.

```
qpdf --encrypt test123 test123 40 -- doc_without_pass.pdf doc_with_pass.pdf
```

Where test123 is both the user and owner password

To decrypt the pdf file you can use the following

```
qpdf --password=test123 --decrypt doc_with_pass.pdf doc_without_pass2.pdf
```

Answer (score 6):

[QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) is capable of encrypting a file with 256-bit encryption keys and AES (or the default RC4 with 40, 128 or 256 bit key lengths).  The relevant information and command line options are in the [QPDF manual](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.encryption-options).

Comment: Thank you for the information I checked the manual several times now  but I am not sure what to type into the terminal, could you please provide a simple example how to do it?

Comment: @Emma it looks like you just need to set the key length to 128 and then add the `--use-aes=y` flag e.g. `qpdf --encrypt <user-password> <owner-password> 128 --use-aes=y -- somefile.pdf somefile_encrypted.pdf` where `<user-password>` and `<owner-password>` are passwords of your choice.

Comment: Very strange. I tried encrypting a file with the command `qpdf --encrypt test123 test123 256 -- input.pdf encrypted.pdf`. It produces a file `encrypted.pdf` that can be correctly decrypted with `qpdf --password=test123 --decrypt encrypted.pdf decrypted.pdf` however, when I try to directly open `encrypted.pdf` with evince or okular and I'm asked for the password, I input `test123` but it says that the password is wrong...

Comment: That's because Evince doesn't support AES yet, see this bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726598. Also, here is a list of different encryption methods corresponding to different PDF versions: https://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/pdf-password-security/encryption/.